# Gutter issue with Bootstrap 2.3.2 on Phone view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-2

Heyho !

Generally, I work with the Bootstrap 3.3+ but for a specific freelancing mission, I have to work under the 2.3.2 version. 
I have an undefined issue under Phone view at the right of the layout.

I really don't understand how to deal with the Phone view under 2.3.2 version.

You can check the whole page here > [http://bp-design.fr/Codeur](http://bp-design.fr/Codeur/)

Comment: Can you please be clear and precise about the issue you are having?

Comment: I don't understand why I have an horizontal scrollbar. Maybe a problem of a `<div>` ? Or a `row` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the left and right margin from `<div id="footer">` and `<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">` the horizontal scrollbar disappears.

Comment: I removed :  `.navbar-fixed-top` and the margins on the `footer`. The horizontal scrollbar is always there :s

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It was an issue with the 3 blocks in blue under my `hero-unit`. Just a CSS bug, not a Bootstrap problem.

Thanks for all your replies mates !